# getting unauthorized response from Identity server4

Tags: identityserver4

I am working on Api to Api using identity server4
Api1 is .net core Api which is the client on IS4, api 1 is getting token from IS4
and sending rest request to api2 which is .net web Api (not .net core).

When running all of this on local host including the IS4 everything is working just fine once I am publishing the IS4 on IIS and directing my web API's to it , API 1 is getting the token and sending the request to API2 but the response is coming back as unauthorized.

Any Idea ? any one ?

enter code here

```
public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {                       
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://<IdentityServer>:8081/",               
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api2" },            
        });

        app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
    }
}
```

enter code here

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
        = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But as l mentioned it is all working just fine when working on local host , the problem only starts when publishing the identity server to iis

Comment: Also api1 is not sending the token, he is using it in rest request header

Comment: @mosheKassabi do you have OWIN logs enabled on API2? if no I have instruction to enable it here https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-web-api/ If you enable the log you will get full as `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` uses OWIN log provider to log the errors

Comment: @nahidf  thanks for the information and the blog , I have manged to Enable the Owin Logs and I get the same error you described "IDX10703" but still , this only happens when I publish to iis , on local I am able to pass

Comment: @mosheKassabi You need to change `AccessTokenJwtType` to `JWT`, I explained it in my blog